# Using a template folder structure

Tags: 2010, folder, copy-and-paste

In my team, we're all new in SharePoint and want to use it for our project file storage.
A template folder structure consists of 7 folders in one main folder.
6 of this 7 folders need special permissions (only viewable for admins), the 7th folder should be open for everybody.

So everytime we have a new project, we should only be able to duplicate this template folder, rename it and can start to work, without always setting up the permissions.
How can I setup this?

WHAT I'VE ALREADY TRIED:
Just to copy/paste the template folder. The template folder is stored under "public", the 7th folder permission is inherited, the other 6 have their own permissions.
But the problem is, when I copy a folder, the permissions aren't maintained. It would be only possible with a macro ([Copy a folder from one library to another and maintain permissions on the folder structure](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/41884/32371)). But this is not possible for our team...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to what you are looking for:

Microsoft Support explanation of how you can use templates to copy and paste libraries.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/copy-or-move-a-library-by-using-a-library-template-HA101814157.aspx

"Copy or move a library within a site collection

Do the following steps to copy or move a library from one site to another site within the same site collection.

Step 1: Create a library template

For step-by-step instructions, see Create a library template within a site.

Top of Page

Step 2: Create a new library based on the library template.

To copy a library, you create a new library based on the library template you created in Step 1: Create a library template.
1. Navigate to the site where you want to create the library. 
2. Click Site Actions , click View All Site Content, and then click Create .

Note    A SharePoint site can be significantly modified in appearance and navigation. If you cannot locate an option, such as a command, button, or link, contact your administrator.

1. Under Libraries, select the library template created in Step 1: Create a library template.
2. Type the Name for the library. Name is required. 
   The name appears at the top of the library in most views, becomes part of the Web address for the library page, and appears in site navigation to help users to find the library. You can change the name of a library, but the Web address will remain the same.
3. Type the Description for the library. Description is optional. 
   The description appears below the name in most views. Some types of libraries can receive content by e-mail. If you plan to enable the library to receive content by e-mail, you can add the e-mail address of the library to its description, so that people can easily find the e-mail address. You can change the description for a library.
4. To add a link to this library on the Quick Launch, verify that Yes is selected in the Navigation section.
5. If there is an E-mail section, your administrator has enabled libraries on your site to receive content by e-mail. To enable people to add content to this library by sending e-mail, click Yes under Enable this library to receive e-mail. Then, in the Email address box, type the first part of the address that you want people to use for the library. This option is not available for all types of libraries.
6. Click Create." MS Support (Copy or move a library by using a library template)

Comment: Please add the main steps from the link to your post, that way your answer will still be helpful if the link breaks

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this is only for whole document-librarys. But my target is a simple folder with sub-folders inside the "public"-library...

Comment: Why not have a new library for each project?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to use workflow for this? Everytime you want a new folder you would start a workflow, enter a name of the project and then workflow steps would create main folder, subfolders and set permissions?