# How to copy the folder structure and permissions with in the same library

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, permissions, pnp-powershell, subfolders

I have a document libray with structure like given below: FolderA->Subfolder1->item1
                                                       Subfolder2-->item2
They have folder level permissions . now i want to create the same folder structure and permissions with different Folder Parent name for example:

Once we copy the folder structure should be FOLDER B-->Subfolder1->item1
                                                       Subfolder2-->item2

This is for sharepointonline CSOM powershell.

I was able to copy the folder structure but unable to get permissions is anything missing

```
       Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll"

Function Copy-SPOFolder([String]$SiteURL, [String]$SourceFolderURL, [String]$TargetFolderURL)
{
    $Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
    Try{
        #Copy the Folder
        $MoveCopyOpt = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyOptions
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyUtil]::CopyFolder($ctx, $SourceFolderURL, $TargetFolderURL, $MoveCopyOpt)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-host -f Green "Folder Copied Successfully!" }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Copying the Folder!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
function Connect-SPO()
{
    param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)][string]$Username,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)][string]$Url,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)]$AdminPassword)
    $global:ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $AdminPassword)
    $ctx.Load($ctx.Web)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
}
#Function to Get Folder Permissions
Function Get-SPOFolderPermission([String]$SiteURL, [String]$FolderRelativeURL)
{
    $Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
    Try{


        #Get the Folder
        $Folder = $ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($FolderRelativeURL)
        $ctx.Load($Folder)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Get permissions assigned to the Folder
        $RoleAssignments = $Folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments
        $ctx.Load($RoleAssignments)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Loop through each permission assigned and extract details
        $PermissionCollection = @()
        Foreach($RoleAssignment in $RoleAssignments)
        {
            $ctx.Load($RoleAssignment.Member)
            $ctx.executeQuery()

            #Get the User Type
            $PermissionType = $RoleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType

            #Get the Permission Levels assigned
            $ctx.Load($RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()


                    $PermissionLevels = ($RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","
                    #Get the User/Group Name
                     $Name = $RoleAssignment.Member.Title # $RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName

                        #Add the Data to Object
                        $Permissions = New-Object PSObject
                        $Permissions | Add-Member NoteProperty Name($Name)
                        $Permissions | Add-Member NoteProperty Type($PermissionType)
                        $Permissions | Add-Member NoteProperty PermissionLevels($PermissionLevels)
                        $PermissionCollection += $Permissions

        }
        Return $PermissionCollection
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Getting Folder Permissions!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
#variables

$admin="santosh.sandy@micrososft.sharepoint.com"
$pass= ConvertTo-SecureString "TSDTD" -AsPlainText -Force
$SiteURL="https://sandy.sharepoint.com/sites/hgs_demo/"
$LibraryName="FolderTest";
$SrcFolderName="RootLibrary"
$NewFolderName="RootLibrary1"
$global:ctx
Try {
    Connect-SPO -Username $admin -Url $SiteURL -AdminPassword $pass
    $Library=$ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName);
    $Folders = $Library.RootFolder.Folders
    $ctx.Load($Library);
    $ctx.Load($Folders)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()        
    #Get existing folder names
    $FolderNames = $Folders | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
    if($FolderNames -contains $NewFolderName)
    {
        write-host "Folder Exists Already!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    else{


        $SourceFolderURL= $SiteURL + $LibraryName +"/" + $SrcFolderName
        $TargetFolderURL= $SiteURL + $LibraryName +"/" + $NewFolderName 
        Copy-SPOFolder $SiteURL $SourceFolderURL $TargetFolderURL
        $ctx.Load($Library);
        $ctx.Load($Folders)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        $FolderNames = $Folders | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        if($FolderNames -contains $NewFolderName)
        {
            $FolderRelativeURL= "/sites/hgs_demo/"+ $LibraryName +"/" + $NewFolderName
            # write-host "Folder Exists Already!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            $cFolder = $ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($FolderRelativeURL)
            $ctx.Load($cFolder)
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

            #Break Permission inheritence - Remove all existing list permissions & keep Item level permissions
            $cFolder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($False,$True)
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            Write-host -f Yellow "Folder's Permission inheritance broken..."
            $copyfolderRetaltiveurl= "/sites/hgs_demo/"+ $LibraryName +"/" + $SrcFolderName
            $PermissionCopy=  Get-SPOFolderPermission $SiteURL $copyfolderRetaltiveurl
            foreach($Permission in $PermissionCopy)
          {

           Write-Host $Permission.Name +".." $Permission.Type +"..." $Permission.PermissionLevels

           if($Permission.Type -eq "User")
           {
             $UserAccount =$Permission.Name
           }
           else{

           $GroupName = $Permission.Name

           }
            #Get the SharePoint Group & User
            $Group =$ctx.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName($GroupName)
            $User = $ctx.Web.EnsureUser($UserAccount)
            $ctx.load($Group)
            $ctx.load($User)
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

            #Grant permission
    #Get the role required
    $Role = $ctx.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName($Permission.PermissionLevels)
    $RoleDB = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($ctx)
    $RoleDB.Add($Role)

    #Assign permissions
    $GroupPermissions = $cFolder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add($Group,$RoleDB)
    $UserPermissions = $cFolder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add($User,$RoleDB)
    $cFolder.Update()
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    Write-host "Permission Granted Successfully!" -ForegroundColor Green 

          }#end of for each loop     
        }
    }
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error Granting permission to  Folder!" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Comment: Hi Sandy, I'm writing this as a comment rather than an Answer because I think you need a coding solution to this.  But it is possible to do this through the List Settings > Save Document Library As Template.  You'd need to test whether the folder-level permissions are preserved.  This works for SP 2013, I've not used SPO.

Comment: Already done .Folder Level Permissions are preserved . As you said i need it through code

Comment: I changed the code but I am unable to get the folder permission copied

Comment: I tried your code but i get error: Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "ExecuteQuery" mit 0 Argument(en): "The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system." I edited the $admin= "admin@domain.de"
and edited the $pass= ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force No MFA activated What do i need to edit to clone a folder with its permissions?
I created a Document Center Library. Its not sites. Its teams Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this below is the code.Can any one help me in making my code small.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll"
########################################
#### Connection Funtions  #############
########################################

function Connect-SPO()
{
    param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)][string]$Username,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)][string]$Url,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)]$AdminPassword)
    $global:ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $AdminPassword)
    $ctx.Load($ctx.Web)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
}

########################################
#### Recurse Function  #################
########################################      
function Recurse($Folder) 
{
$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"

    $folderName = $Folder.Name
    $folderItemCount = $folder.ItemCount
    Write-Host "Folder Name ->'$folderName'"
    Write-Host "Number of List Items->'$folderItemCount'"


    if($Folder.name -eq $SrcFolderName)
    {

          $Rootfolderurl= $Folder.ServerRelativeUrl
          $NewRootFolder=$RootfolderURl.Replace($SrcFolderName,$NewFolderName)
          Write-Host $Rootfolderurl -ForegroundColor Magenta
          Write-Host $NewRootFolder -ForegroundColor Magenta


          ###########################
          #Create the new Root Folder
          ##########################
          ###Create-Folder -LibraryName $LibraryName -FolderName $NewFolderName -RootPermissionCol $RootPermissionCopy


          #Create the Folder
          $CreateNewFolder=$ctx.Web.Folders.Add($NewRootFolder)
          $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
          Write-Host "Folder Created"

          #############################
          ###Get Security on RootFolder
          #############################

          $RootPermissionCopy=  Get-SPOFolderPermission -FolderRelativeURL $Rootfolderurl

          #############################
          ###Break Inheritence on New Root Folder
          #############################

          $cFolder = $ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($NewRootFolder)
          $ctx.Load($cFolder)
          $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

           #Break Permission inheritence - Remove all existing list permissions & keep Item level permissions
           $cFolder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($False,$True)
           $ctx.ExecuteQuery()


          foreach($Permission in $RootPermissionCopy)
          {
              Write-Host "Name " $Permission.Name
              Write-Host "Type " $Permission.Type
              Write-Host "Permission Levels" $Permission.PermissionLevels



              #Check and Skip if Permission are only "Limited Access"
              If ($Permission.PermissionLevels -eq "Limited Access") {
              Write-Host "Skipping because there is only Limited Access"
              Write-Host ""
              }
              Else {
                if($Permission.Type -eq "User"){
                    $PermLevelArray=$Permission.PermissionLevels -split ","
                    $UserAccount =$Permission.Name
                    $User = $ctx.Web.EnsureUser($UserAccount)
                    $ctx.load($User)
                    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

                        Foreach($PermLevel in $PermLevelArray){
                            write-host $PermLevel
                            if($PermLevel -eq "Limited Access") {
                                Write-Host "Skipping Limited Access"
                            }
                            Else {
                                $Role = $ctx.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName($PermLevel)
                                $RoleDB = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($ctx)
                                $RoleDB.Add($Role)
                                $UserPermissions = $cFolder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add($User,$RoleDB)
                                Write-Host "Applied " $PermLevel
                                $cFolder.Update()
                                    try {
                                        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                                    }
                                    Catch {
                                        Write-host "User cannot be found"
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                }
                else{
                    Write-host $Permission.Name
                    $PermLevelArray=$Permission.PermissionLevels -split ","
                    $GroupName = $Permission.Name
                    $Group =$ctx.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName($GroupName)
                    $ctx.load($Group)
                    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

                    Foreach($PermLevel in $PermLevelArray){
                        write-host $PermLevel
                        if($PermLevel -eq "Limited Access") {
                            Write-Host "Skipping Limited Access"
                        }
                        Else {
                            $Role = $ctx.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName($PermLevel)
                            $RoleDB = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($ctx)
                            $RoleDB.Add($Role)
                            $GroupPermissions = $cFolder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add($Group,$RoleDB)
                            Write-Host "Applied " $PermLevel
                            $cFolder.Update()
                            Try {
                                $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                            }
                            Catch {
                                Write-host "Group Cannot be Found"
                            }
                       }
                    }
                }

              }

          }

          Write-Host "Permissions Retrieved"


    }

    Else
    {
    ################################
    ##Create New SubFolder
    ################################

       Write-Host "Copy this folder as a none root folder!!" -ForegroundColor Cyan

       #Get Relative Url of the Folder to Copy
       $CurrentFolderUrl= $Folder.ServerRelativeUrl
       Write-Host $CurrentFolderUrl -ForegroundColor Green

       #Create Url of the Folder to Create based on the Current Folder - Replace Folder Path
       $FolderToAdd = $CurrentFolderUrl.Replace($SrcFolderName,$NewFolderName)
       Write-Host "Add===> "$FolderToAdd -ForegroundColor Cyan



       #Create the Folder
       $CreateNewFolder=$ctx.Web.Folders.Add($FolderToAdd)
       $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
       Write-Host "Folder Created"

       #############################
       ###Get Security on Current Folder
       #############################
       $CurrentPermissionCopy=  Get-SPOFolderPermission -FolderRelativeURL $CurrentFolderUrl

       #############################
       ###Break Inheritence on New Root Folder
       #############################

       $cFolder = $ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($FolderToAdd)
       $ctx.Load($cFolder)
       $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

       #Break Permission inheritence - Remove all existing list permissions & keep Item level permissions
       $cFolder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($False,$True)
       $ctx.ExecuteQuery()


          foreach($Permission in $CurrentPermissionCopy)
          {
              Write-Host "Name " $Permission.Name
              Write-Host "Type " $Permission.Type
              Write-Host "Permission Levels" $Permission.PermissionLevels



              #Check and Skip if Permission are only "Limited Access"
              If ($Permission.PermissionLevels -eq "Limited Access") {
              Write-Host "Skipping because there is only Limited Access"
              Write-Host ""
              }
              Else {
                if($Permission.Type -eq "User"){
                    $PermLevelArray=$Permission.PermissionLevels -split ","
                    $UserAccount =$Permission.Name
                    $User = $ctx.Web.EnsureUser($UserAccount)
                    $ctx.load($User)
                    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

                        Foreach($PermLevel in $PermLevelArray){
                            write-host $PermLevel
                            if($PermLevel -eq "Limited Access") {
                                Write-Host "Skipping Limited Access"
                            }
                            Else {
                                $Role = $ctx.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName($PermLevel)
                                $RoleDB = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($ctx)
                                $RoleDB.Add($Role)
                                $UserPermissions = $cFolder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add($User,$RoleDB)
                                Write-Host "Applied " $PermLevel
                                $cFolder.Update()
                                    try {
                                        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                                    }
                                    Catch {
                                        Write-host "User cannot be found"
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                }
                else{
                    Write-host $Permission.Name
                    $PermLevelArray=$Permission.PermissionLevels -split ","
                    $GroupName = $Permission.Name
                    $Group =$ctx.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName($GroupName)
                    $ctx.load($Group)
                    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

                    Foreach($PermLevel in $PermLevelArray){
                        write-host $PermLevel
                       if($PermLevel -eq "Limited Access") {
                            Write-Host "Skipping Limited Access"
                        }
                        Else {
                            $Role = $ctx.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName($PermLevel)
                            $RoleDB = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($ctx)
                            $RoleDB.Add($Role)
                            $GroupPermissions = $cFolder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add($Group,$RoleDB)
                            Write-Host "Applied " $PermLevel
                            $cFolder.Update()
                            Try {
                                $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                            }
                            Catch {
                                Write-host "Group Cannot be Found"
                            }
                       }
                    }
                }

              }

          }

       }



    #Write-Host $folder.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
    $thisFolder = $ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($Folder.ServerRelativeUrl)
    $ctx.Load($thisFolder)
    $ctx.Load($thisFolder.Folders)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    foreach($subfolder in $thisFolder.Folders)
        {
           Write-Host $subfolder.ServerRelativeUrl -ForegroundColor Gray
            Recurse $subfolder  
        }       
}

##########################################
#### Function to Get Folder Permissions ## 
##########################################
Function Check-SPOFolderExists()
{
  param
    ( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $FolderRelativeURL)

    $Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
       $checkfolderExists="False"

    Try {
          #Check Folder Exists
          $checkfolder= $ctx.web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($FolderRelativeURL)
          $ctx.Load($Folder)
          $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
          $checkfolderExists="True";
          #Write-host -f Green "Folder Exists!"
        }

    catch{
           Write-host -f Yellow "Folder Doesn't Exist!"
            #Write-Host "Error in Check-SPoFolder Function with Message" $_.Exception.Message
        }

    return $checkfolderExists

 }


##########################################
#### Function to Get Folder Permissions ## 
##########################################

Function Get-SPOFolderPermission([String]$FolderRelativeURL)
{
    $Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
    Try{


        #Get the Folder
        $pFolder = $ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($FolderRelativeURL)
        $ctx.Load($pFolder)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Get permissions assigned to the Folder
        $RoleAssignments = $pFolder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments
        $ctx.Load($RoleAssignments)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Loop through each permission assigned and extract details
        $PermissionCollection = @()
        Foreach($RoleAssignment in $RoleAssignments)
       {
            $ctx.Load($RoleAssignment.Member)
            $ctx.executeQuery()

            #Get the User Type
            $PermissionType = $RoleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType

            #Get the Permission Levels assigned
            $ctx.Load($RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()


                    $PermissionLevels = ($RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","
                    #Get the User/Group Name
                     $Name = $RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName # $RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName

                        #Add the Data to Object
                        $Permissions = New-Object PSObject
                        $Permissions | Add-Member NoteProperty Name($Name)
                        $Permissions | Add-Member NoteProperty Type($PermissionType)
                        $Permissions | Add-Member NoteProperty PermissionLevels($PermissionLevels)
                        $PermissionCollection += $Permissions

        }
        Return $PermissionCollection
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Getting Folder Permissions!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}

##################################
#### Parmeters and start script ## 
##################################

$admin=""
$pass= ConvertTo-SecureString "" -AsPlainText -Force
$SiteURL="https://micrososft.sharepoint.com/sites/hgs_demo/"
$LibraryName="FolderTest";
$SrcFolderName="mytest"
$NewFolderName="cmytesst"
$global:ctx
Try {
     Connect-SPO -Username $admin -Url $SiteURL -AdminPassword $pass
    $Library=$ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName);
    $Folders = $Library.RootFolder.Folders
    $ctx.Load($Library);
    $ctx.Load($Folders)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()   

    foreach ($Folder in $Library.RootFolder.Folders)
        {

        if($Folder.ItemCount -gt 0 -and $Folder.Name -eq $SrcFolderName)
         {
              $CurrentRootfolderurl= $Folder.ServerRelativeUrl
            $NewRootFolderUrl=$CurrentRootfolderurl.Replace($SrcFolderName,$NewFolderName)
          #CheckIfFolderExists
           $CheckRootFolderExists= Check-SPOFolderExists -FolderRelativeURL $NewRootFolderUrl
           if( $CheckRootFolderExists -eq "True")
           {

               Write-Host "A folder with name "$NewFolderName "already Exists and its url " $NewRootFolderUrl -ForegroundColor Green
           }
           else{
            #Calling Recursive Function with
                Recurse $Folder
             }
           }
        }



    }

    catch{

    Write-Host  $_.Exception.Message

    }
```