# Copy Sharepoint subfolder (template) and apply copy permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, subfolders

Is there a way of amending this script here:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/263621/89177

to be able to copy/create and apply perms to subfolders? (E.g: https://micrososft.sharepoint.com/sites/hgs_demo -> LibraryName -> Template Folder -> SubFolder 1 etc?

I've tried amending the variables but it doesn't seem to be able to 'find' subfolders.

TIA
Phil

Comment: The script you are linking to already copies all subfolders.

Comment: Hi Willman, it only works for folders on the root of the document library, I would like to be able to duplicate a folder (with perms) underneath this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the entire script as written, except for the section `#### Parmeters and start script ##`, then use the below:

```
##################################
#### Parmeters and start script ## 
##################################

$admin=""
$pass= ConvertTo-SecureString "" -AsPlainText -Force
$SiteURL="https://micrososft.sharepoint.com/sites/hgs_demo/"
$LibraryName="FolderTest";
$SourceFolderServerRelativeUrl="/sites/hgs_demo/libname/subfolder1"
$DestinationFolderServerRelativeUrl="/sites/hgs_demo/libname/folder0/destFolder1"
$global:ctx
Try 
{
    Connect-SPO -Username $admin -Url $SiteURL -AdminPassword $pass
    $Library=$ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName);
    $SrcFolder = $ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($SrcFolderServerRelativePath);
    $ctx.Load($Library);
    $ctx.Load($SrcFolder)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()   

    #CheckIfFolderExists
    $CheckRootFolderExists= Check-SPOFolderExists -FolderRelativeURL $DestinationFolderServerRelativeUrl
    if( $CheckRootFolderExists -eq "True")
    {
        Write-Host "A folder "$DestinationFolderServerRelativeUrl "already Exists" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else
    {
        #Calling Recursive Function with
        Recurse $SrcFolder
    }
}
catch
{

    Write-Host  $_.Exception.Message

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However I've just tried it and it's throwing an 'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression' error

Comment: sorry, just noticed there was a typo `$ctw` instead of `$ctx`

Comment: Thanks willman. Just been having a play around in our environment and it keeps throwing the following no matter how I tweak the library, source or destination paths:
Folder Doesn't Exist!
Folder Name ->''
Number of List Items->'0'
Copy this folder as a none root folder!!
/sites/hgs_demo/
Add===>  /sites/hgs_demo/
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "File Not Found."

Comment: You have to update these variables to match your folder and library names: `$LibraryName=`   `$SourceFolderServerRelativeUrl=`  `$DestinationFolderServerRelativeUrl=`

Comment: Yeah done that but that's the error it throws. I think it relates to something within the  ##Create New SubFolder section of the code