# SharePoint: Clone/Copy Folder including permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, folder

I read several topics. Most of them are old.

Is there actually a way to clone/copy a folder in a SharePoint Document Library with its permissions?

I have to create 10 Folders for several external customers.

In this folders there are many folders with different rights for the employees.

But all folders have all the same structure.

So can I clone/copy the first folder as a template?

I work with security groups.

Comment: There is no SharePoint out of the box functionality using which you can copy the folder and its permissions. You need to develop custom solution for this using PowerShell or workflow or something else which you can develop easily.

Comment: Hello Ganesh.
Thanks for your answer.
I found this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/263334/how-to-copy-the-folder-structure-and-permissions-with-in-the-same-library/287957#287957

But i stuck in the login from this script. 
 "The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system."
Can you help there?
Thank you :)